# ListView showing all content

Tags: android, listview

I'm aware that there's been a lot Q&A on this topic, but i still didn't find the right answer.

I want my ListView (inside of a ScrollView) to 'expand' over the bottom edge of the screen to show all of the items without need for scrollbar therefore it wouldn't be a problem to put ListView inside ScrollView and we would be able to scroll whole activity.

Puting items collection in LinearLayout is not a solution - it's just to damn slow. It takes 2-3 sec to draw 100 items while ListView does it instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `ListView`'s `layout_height` to `wrap_content`, but then it would be as slow as the LinearLayout. The whole point of `ListView` is that its content is fake; it only creates the rows that are visible within its height. Making it as tall as its content would take away its advantage.

I'd suggest re-thinking what you're trying to do. Perhaps you can put all of your widgets inside the `ListView` and then you wouldn't need a `ScrollView`.

Comment: About re-thinking :) I need to display some data besides List. That data takes vertical space. If I want my user to see as much list as possible i have to remove that other data from the screen. Best way to do that is to scroll down. In that way I'm certain what user wants - to see just List. I really don't know is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't resolve my problem because at the time there was no way to do any Footer or Header views with MvvmCross that I was using. I dunno if it is possible to do it now. It took me few months to convince my clients that tabs are the right way to go with Android. So I actually didn't resolve this problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set Listview's height at runtime by using this snippet

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup)
                listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

And example to use this

```
listComment.setAdapter(new CommentAdapter(comment,
                        AppDetailActivity.this));
                listComment.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Utils.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listComment);

                    }
                }, 500);
```